# How do lambda layers handle conflicting files names when multiple layers are applied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-lambda-layers

New to aws and have an question involving how layers are applied to lambdas using terraform. I have a lambda that has utilizes a layer that is a custom bash runtime for the lambda. This layer generates and downloads some certs necessary for the lambda to run and stores them as a `certs.crt` file within a `/opt` folder inside the lambda. If I create another layer that pulls a different set of certs and saves them within same `/opt` folder with the same name (`certs.crt`), would the file from the previous layer be overridden? My terraform file looks something like this

```
module "test_lambda" {
  source = "../../modules/lambda/basic"
  filename = "${module.test_lambda_artifact.artifact}"
  function_name = "test-lambda"
  handler = "function.handler"
  runtime = "provided"
  description = "test lambda"
  environment="${var.aws_env}"

  layers = ["${data.aws_lambda_layer_version.layer1.arn}", "${data.aws_lambda_layer_version.layer2.arn}"]
  memory_size = 2048
  timeout = 60
}
```

Any help would be appreciated and I apologize for any lack of clarity/termanology as I am new to aws and terraform.

Comment: Well, the first question I have is why name the certs the same way?

Comment: The layer doesn't "generate and downloads some certs". The layer includes the certs, and AWS Lambda extracts the layer contents into the /opt directory. Lambda merges folders with the same name, so if the same file appears in multiple layers, the function uses the version in the last extracted layer. No, it won't know that you want to combine those two same-named cert files.

Comment: I was expecting them to be combined, was more just wondering if the certs file from layer 2 would overwrite the certs file from layer 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lambda merges folders with the same name, so if the same file appears in multiple layers, the function uses the version in the last extracted layer.

From the [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html#invocation-layers-accessing)